# Why aren't these faces extruded as the tutorial video?

Tags: subdivision-surface, scale

I was following a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/X2lw9JwTrI8?t=159), and when the presenter "hit 's' and scale forward...", they looked like the first screenshot below. But when I did that, the direction that those faces were extruding to were different as the second and third screenshots below. Notice the bottom low faces; they are extruding upwards, instead of downwards as the tutorial. Why is it so? The blender project [file is here](https://filebin.net/749dqned0o00eydq/damn.blend?t=e3w3lwti).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of overlapping vertices which seem to be effecting the scaling operation.

To remove these:

1. In **Edit mode** select **All** of the model.
2. Open the **Vertex menu**.
3. Select the **Merge Vertices**.
4. Select the **By Distance** option.

At the bottom of the screen you will see how many vertices have been removed.

[image]

Now re select the 8 faces, and they will scale as shown in the video.

[image]